# Android Studio Duplicate class kotlin

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31)

Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.3.31 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.31)

**./gradlew clean **

build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
    
    firebase: [
        bom           : "26.0.0"
    ]
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {

        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0" 
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"

    }
}
def REACT_NATIVE_VERSION = new File(['node', '--print',"JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(require.resolve('react-native/package.json'), 'utf-8')).version"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim())
allprojects {
    repositories {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy {

                force "com.facebook.react:react-native:" + REACT_NATIVE_VERSION
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()
        maven {

            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {

            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `build.gradle`?

Comment: Yes in question @YaMiN

Comment: Were you by any chance using react-native-inappbrowser? I described the issue here: https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/398

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks all, I solve it by doing two things

In android/build.gradle update the following

`kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"`

In android/app/build.gradle add the following in dependencies

`implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))`

Comment: in my case works by updating the kotlin version to `1.8.0`, no need to add the `kotlin-bom` dependency,

Comment: @ZainalFahrudin how do you update the kotlin version?

Comment: No need to change the `android/build.gradle` of you're not using the variable in `android/app/build.gradle`. Otherwise you should write `implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:$kotlinVersion"))`, like [narasimha's answer you copied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75245549/1098603) (instead of accepting his answer).

Answer (score 27):

I had the same problem with my app. It failed to build because of duplicate classes found in modules `jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0` and `jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.10`

With the link, shared by Igor VANIAN : https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#usage-of-the-latest-kotlin-stdlib-version-in-transitive-dependencies
I added

```
dependencies {
    ...

    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
}
```

to my `android/app/build.gradle` and Android builds fine now

Comment: Saved my life. I was going bananas with this sudden error without any change on my project. Not cool, kotlin people!

Comment: This also works for me when adding CameraX elements to my projects. Thank you so much.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts.

Answer (score 5):

I started having the same issue in react native native on the android side. I upgraded Kotlin to version 1.8.0 and built the app again and the issue was fixed. Maybe trying upgrading the kotlin version.

In android/build.gradle update the following

```
kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
```

and add this under dependencies

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem since yesterday.
I found that the reason behind this could be the [artifact merge in Kotlin 1.8.0](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/whatsnew18.html#updated-jvm-compilation-target). Here is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55297/kotlin-stdlib-should-declare-constraints-on-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-and-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7) talking about this breaking change.

So setting kotlinVersion = "1.8.0" as @Narasimha said works. But I still didn't figure out what dependency changed overnight that somehow made kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0 appear in the build logs.

Comment: Yes, totally agree. App was running fine in the morning I made a commit checkout to different branch and try to run it and the error starts popping.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when you're using different versions for different Kotlin dependencies.

Try to check all Kotlin dependencies. In my case, issue was with this **core-ktx**

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Updating to this resolved issue

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
```

Here `kotlin_version = '1.7.0'`. You can use your desired version.
Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and I fixed it in a different way, if it helps anyone:
When I upgraded my kotlin to version 1.8 it started happening and I had to change my hilt version to 2.44. Now it's running normally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).