# React-Native Android build error Task ":app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses"

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I'm developing a mobile app and everything was working fine, building even made `./gradlew bundleRelease`, everything was working, and then suddenly this error:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
  Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.0.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.4.10)
```

This is my versions:

```
ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        kotlinVersion = "1.4.10"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
        playServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
    }
...
...
...
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1' // after
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion")
        // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

build.gradle file

These are my dependancies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^0.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "2.0.10",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.8.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.50",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lottie-ios": "3.1.8",
    "lottie-react-native": "^3.5.0",
    "mobx": "^5.15.4",
    "mobx-react": "^6.1.8",
    "mobx-state-tree": "^3.15.0",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-devtools-core": "3",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-android-location-enabler": "1.1.0",
    "react-native-axios": "^0.17.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.265.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.4",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.1.5",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-google-signin": "^2.1.1",
    "react-native-ibm-mobilefirst": "^8.0.2021040715",
    "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.4.0",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",
    "react-native-navigation": "6.4.0",
    "react-native-navigation-hooks": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-phone-call": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-picker-select": "^8.0.4",
    "react-native-shadow": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-swipeable": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^9.2.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0"
  }
```

package.json file

This is implementations:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-geolocation-service')
    implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
 
    implementation project(':react-native-android-location-enabler')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_netinfo')
    implementation project(':@notifee_react-native')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
      //Add these lines
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:19.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:19.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:17.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0"

    implementation project(':react-native-inappbrowser-reborn')
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.1'

    compile project(':oppwa.mobile-2.49.0')
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-navigation')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_geolocation')
    implementation project(':react-native-maps')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    // implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.0"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    implementation project(path: ':oppwa.mobile-2.49.0')  // From node_modules

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Can you help me guys?

I tries the most of what is offered in *this* and other sites. Nothing helped.

Everything was working fine, and suddenly this happened.

Comment: Duplicate with : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75245549/7140328
This is currently working for us.

Comment: @IgorVANIAN I made like @Narashima said. Now I have a new error: `Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.0`

Comment: I think you should try only specifying kotlinVersion and ignore the gradle plugin line. Like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75249817

Comment: @IgorVANIAN I tried both ways, with gradle plugin line and without. Same thing.

Comment: Did you update your gradle to 7.6 by any chance? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55714

Comment: I ran into the same error as well. One other reason I like Flutter more than react native hah

Comment: @Dinesh But, objectively, what do you think is better, React Native or Flutter? and why?
Trying to learn stuff from experienced developers :)

Comment: @SuleimanZhukov - I personally like Flutter because of tooling such as IDE and CLI, multi-threading, cross-compiling for different architecture is a breeze, you can do easy FFI with Rust and C, code-generation, and transparency & you can modify low level stuff. Also, there are pretty interesting things gonna happen in upcoming release - Macros (i.e., annotations), impeller rendering engine (which lets you import 3d models from blender.). Mainly, it does not randomly break because their CLI is so good it can resolve the dependencies for you. many more.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding the following line in `andoird/app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

 . . .

 // Add this line here
 implementation platform('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0')
 . . .

}
```

> Not sure if you want to commit this in your source control though. As it might be likely be because of something was changed in your environment.

Hope this helps.