# React-Native Android build error: Could not find io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.7

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I'm developing a mobile app and everything was working fine, building, and even made `./gradlew bundleRelease`, everything was working, and then suddenly my first error:
(This was my question)
[React-Native Android build error Task ":app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75246578/react-native-android-build-error-task-appcheckdebugduplicateclasses)

But I fixed it, now I have this error: `:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac`

```
buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 21
compileSdkVersion = 31
targetSdkVersion = 31
```

And this it the error:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.7.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :@notifee_react-native
         project :app > project :notifee_react-native
   > Could not find com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0-rc01
   > Could not find com.facebook.infer.annotation:infer-annotation:0.11.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find javax.inject:javax.inject:1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find com.facebook.fresco:imagepipeline-okhttp3:2.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.6.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.12.1.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find com.squareup.okio:okio:1.15.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > com.facebook.react:react-native:0.61.5
   > Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.annotation:annotation-jvm:1.6.0-beta01
```

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        kotlinVersion = "1.4.0"
        RNNKotlinVersion = kotlinVersion
        playServicesVersion = "16.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
          url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1" // after
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0"
        classpath "io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+"
        classpath "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt-api:0.10.7"
    }
}
```

Tried many things. Nothing works.

Comment: I didn't do nothing, and  now I have this `Could not find com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.4.0`

Comment: And I made the unlinking thing in `react-native.config.js` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is the solution basically.

You need to add this code to `dependancies` in `app/build.gradle`:

```
constraints {
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
    because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
  }
  implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
    because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
  }
}
```

And `ndkVersion "25.1.8937393"` to `android` in the same file, like this:

```
android {
  ndkVersion "25.1.8937393" // <- Add this line
}
```

Also change version to `6.9` in `android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, like this:
`/gradle-6.9-all.zip`

In `android/build.gradle`, my kotlin is `1.6.21` and `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1`.

Happy coding