# Duplicate class errors in newly created app

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created simple basic view java appication in Android studio. After application creation wizard has finished I tried to run it. Got many Duplicate class errors.

Is something wrong with my android studio installation? How to fix that?

But why it complains about Kotlin. I'm creating Android Java project

```
Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.21 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.21)
```

Content of build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.kkk.basic_view3'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.kkk.basic_view3"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.6.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75243778/android-studio-duplicate-class-kotlin) looks similar to yours. Did you check every kotlin mentions in your `build.gradle` files?

Comment: But why it complains about kotlin. I'm creating Android Java project

Comment: @artaxerx there is no references to `kotlin` in `build.gradle`

Comment: It can be because of implementation android libs(i.e. constraintLayout, navigation ui, navigation-fragment) you have added..they might be using different version of stdlib